# Open Pipe Thickness & Fundamental Frequency

Tags: harmonics

Does the thickness of an open pipe affect the fundamental frequency of it and how? Is there an equation relating the two?

Answer (score 1):

If the pipe is assumed to be rigid, the only effect is a second-order term in the end correction factor.

From the results in http://mellowacoustics.com/articles/Disk_in_a_circular_baffle.pdf (published in 
J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 118 3, Pt. 1, September 2005) the effective radius $r$ in the end correction to the length of the pipe (usually taken as $0.6r$) should be the mean radius of the pipe itself, not the internal radius.

However, this is usually of no practical significance.